# Pagination in Swiper in Ionic project does not have a part for pagination

Tags: ionic-framework, pagination, swiper.js

I implemented Swiper (version 10.0.4) in my Ionic 7.2.0 project, but the generated pagination does not have a ::part(pagination)

```
<div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-bullets swiper-pagination-horizontal">
    <span part="bullet-active" class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active" aria-current="true"></span>
    <span part="bullet" class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span>
</div>
```

So there are only parts for bullet and bullet-active, but the documentation says the pagination part should also be active.
https://swiperjs.com/element#parts

I cannot change css even with .swiper-pagination-bullets selector in my globals.scss.

How can I change the css of the swiper-pagination-bullets div?

Thank you